# Chrome extension javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0u6W.png

For some context look at the image provided,

There are 3 type of box that appears in the site automatically every few seconds, "Hi", "Hello" and "Hey".
You can click the box and it will be added to the right side.

```
    <div class="h-240 rounded relative bg-gray-400 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-300 transition duration-75 ease-in-out">

<span class="inline-block ml-10 text-gray-200"> (Hello)</span>

</div>

<div class="h-240 rounded relative bg-gray-400 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-300 transition duration-75 ease-in-out">

<span class="inline-block ml-10 text-gray-200"> (Hi)</span>
```

```
<div class="h-240 rounded relative bg-gray-400 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-300 transition duration-75 ease-in-out">

    <span class="inline-block ml-10 text-gray-200"> (Hey)</span>

</div>

<div class="h-240 rounded relative bg-gray-400 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-300 transition duration-75 ease-in-out">

        <span class="inline-block ml-10 text-gray-200"> (Hey)</span>

    </div>

 <div class="h-240 rounded relative bg-gray-400 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-300 transition duration-75 ease-in-out">

    <span class="inline-block ml-10 text-gray-200"> (Hello)</span>

    </div>
```

How do I make a content script to automatically click any box with "Hello".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in a background script.  It has to be done in a content script.

> script.js

```js
setInterval(() => {
  document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => {
    div.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML.includes('Hello') && div.click();
  });
}, 1000);
```

> manifest.json

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Hello Box Clicker",
  "permissions": [
  "activeTab"
  ],
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "script.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hey, I tried doing this but it still doesn't click anything. I've added the actual code snippet in the question above. I tried console.log to see box.innerHTML but i'm not getting anything either.

Comment: Your current edit contradicts your original post.  Please post the entire code of all the boxes; otherwise, nobody can help you.

Comment: Sorry about that, had to change the original post as the code got edited.